# Partition a random sequence composed of three numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, algorithm

I want to partition an array composed of `1`s, `2`s and `3`s in such a way that,
going from left to right, each bin (1) contains all three numbers and (2) is as short as possible.

**Some examples:**

```
{1, 1, 1} -> {}

{1, 3, 2, 1} -> {1, 3, 2}

{1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1} -> {{1, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 1, 2}}

{1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1} -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 2, 3, 1}}
```

I tried many variations with `SequenceCases` and similar functions but didn't even come close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
splitByUnion =  Module[{u = {}}, # -> Select[Union @ # === Range @ 3 &] @
   Split[#, x |-> Or[(u = Union[u, {x}]) != Range[3], u = {};]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
lists = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1},
  {1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1}};

splitByUnion /@ lists // Column
```

[image]

```
sequenceSplitByUnion = # -> Select[Union @ # === Range[3] &] @
   SequenceSplit[#, {x : Shortest[__]} /; Union[{x}] == Range[3] :> {x}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Map[sequenceSplitByUnion]@lists === Map[splitByUnion]@lists
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: The code with `SequenceSplit` does not seem to work on 13.0.1.0. It outputs unchanged input. What has changed in latest version?

Comment: @azerbajdzan, I don't know what has changed since version 13.0.1.0. Documentation does not mention any updates to `SequenceSplit` since its introduction.

Comment: It does not have to be change in `SequenceSplit` maybe somewhere else like for example in `Shortest`.

Comment: very good point.

Answer (score 9):

We may scan "list" and add its elements to a temporary list "tmp" until "tmp" fulfills the conditions. Then we store "tmp" and start over. For an example, we first create a random list:

```
Random[1];
list = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}, 15]

{3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}
```

Then we proceed as explained above:

```
tmp = {};
Reap[
 (AppendTo[tmp, #]; 
    If[MemberQ[#, 1] && MemberQ[#, 2] && MemberQ[#, 3] &[tmp], 
     Sow[tmp]; tmp = {}]
    ) & /@ list
][[2, 1]]

{{3, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}}
```

Answer (score 7):

A fancy way:

```
SpecialPartition[list_] :=
  MapAt[If[ContainsAll[#, {1, 2, 3}], #, Nothing] &, -1]@
   FoldPair[
     If[
       ContainsAll[Last[#1], {1, 2, 3}],
       {Null, Append[#1, {#2}]},
       {Null, Insert[#1, #2, {-1, -1}]}] &,
     {{}},
     list,
     Last]
```

Answer (score 7):

A non-fancy way:

````
list = {1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1};
parts = {}; temp = {};
n = 3;
While[n <= Length[list],
 temp = list[[1 ;; n]];
 If[Length[Union[temp]] == 3, {
    parts = Append[parts, temp],
    list = Drop[list, n];
    n = 2};
  ]; n++]

parts
 (* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 2, 3, 1}} *)
```
````

Answer (score 7):

It can be done using `SequenceCases` in one-liner `SequenceCases[r, {x__, y_} /;FreeQ[{x},y]\[And] {x, y} \[Intersection] {1, 2, 3} == {1, 2, 3}]` but "good old" `For` overcomes it in performance 452 times (`7.0625/0.015625=452.`) for list of length only `1000`.

```
r = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}, 1000];
vys1 = SequenceCases[
    r, {x__, y_} /; 
     FreeQ[{x}, 
       y] \[And] {x, y} \[Intersection] {1, 2, 3} == {1, 2, 3}] // 
   Timing;
vys1[[1]]
a = False; b = False; c = False;
s = 1;
vys2 = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[r], i++,
  Which[r[[i]] == 1, a = True, r[[i]] == 2, b = True, True, c = True];
  If[a \[And] b \[And] c, a = False; b = False; c = False; 
   AppendTo[vys2, r[[s ;; i]]]; s = i + 1;]
  ] // Timing
vys1[[2]] == vys2

Clear[r, a, b, c, s, vys1, vys2, i]

(* 7.0625 *)
(* {0.015625, Null} *)
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
SpecialPartition[list_] := SpecialPartition[{{}}, list];
SpecialPartition[groups_, {}] := Select[groups, ContainsAll[{1, 2, 3}]];
SpecialPartition[{previousGroups___, currentGroup_}, list : {next_, ___}] :=
  If[
    ContainsAll[currentGroup, {1, 2, 3}],
    SpecialPartition[{previousGroups, currentGroup, {}}, list],
    SpecialPartition[{previousGroups, Append[currentGroup, next]}, Rest@list]]
```

This is slightly different than your requirements in that

```
SpecialPartition[{1, 3, 2, 1}]
```

gives

```
{{1, 3, 2}}
```

which is more idiomatic for Wolfram Language functions.

I feel like needing `ContainsAll` twice is sub-optimal, but I haven't tried to streamline it.

**Update**

I went ahead and removed the redundancy, by changing the terminal case:

```
SpecialPartition[{previousGroups___, currentGroup_}, {}] :=
  If[
    ContainsAll[currentGroup, {1, 2, 3}],
    {previousGroups, currentGroup},
    {previousGroups}]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `ReplaceList`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
elems = {1, 2, 3};
lists = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 
    3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1}};

allinPartition[k_List, elems_List] := NestWhileList[
     ReplaceList[
       Last@#
       , {a__, b___} /; Union[{a}] == elems :> Sequence[{a}, {b}]
       , 1] &
     , {{}, k}
     , # != {} &
     ] //
    Rest //
   Replace[#, {} -> Nothing, {1}] & // #[[All, 1]] &
```

---

*Usage:*

```
{#, allinPartition[#, elems]} & /@ lists // 
 Grid[#, Alignment -> Left, ItemSize -> {{24, 24}, {1}}] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version
```

13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)

`RepeatedTiming`s of

```
list = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}, 10^5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
f=TakeDrop[Last@#,MinMax@PositionIndex[Last@#][[All,1]]]&;

f@{lst5}

(* {{1,2,3},{1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,3}} *)
```

Combining with [`NestWhileList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html):

```
NestWhileList[f,{lst1},Length@Union@#[[-1]]>2&,1,100][[2;;]][[All,1]]

NestWhileList[f,{lst2},Length@Union@#[[-1]]>2&,1,100][[2;;]][[All,1]]

NestWhileList[f,{lst3},Length@Union@#[[-1]]>2&,1,100][[2;;]][[All,1]]

NestWhileList[f,{lst4},Length@Union@#[[-1]]>2&,1,100][[2;;]][[All,1]]

NestWhileList[f,{lst5},Length@Union@#[[-1]]>2&,1,100][[2;;]][[All,1]]


(* 

{} 
{{1,3,2}} 
{{1,1,2,3},{3,3,1,2}} 
{{1,2,3},{1,1,2,2,3},{3,2,2,3,1}} 
{{1,2,3},{1,1,2,2,3},{3,2,2,3,1},{1,2,2,2,2,3}}

*)
```

**Lists**

```
lst1={1, 1, 1} ;
lst2={1, 3, 2, 1};
lst3={1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1} ;
lst4={1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1};
lst5={1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1,2,2,2,2,3};
```